# Video quality setting with camera.getPicture

Tags: cordova, video, compression, phonegap-plugins

The quality setting works fine on photos but does it work on videos too?

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onVideoURISuccess, onFail, {
    quality: 50, // this does nothing for me
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: 1 // videos only
});
```

Or am I forced to do some kind of video compression of the video instead?

Comment: quality is for images only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user jcesarmobile stated this only works for images.

My solution is to use the https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor plugin instead.